# Having keyboard interact with programs during input Autohotkey

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey

I'm trying to create a program that plays a continuous "beep" sound anytime 3 seconds have passed without any key being pressed. The beep sound continues until another key is pressed, which renews the 3 second countdown.

I want the program to run in the background while I'm typing. However, while the script is running, other programs (such as Microsoft Word) do not respond to keystrokes. I tried setting BlockInput to Off, but that didn't solve the problem. Any ideas on getting the keyboard to interact with other programs? Thanks!

```
loop 
{
Transform, CtrlQ, Chr, 17
Input, KeyPress, L1 M T3
if KeyPress = %CtrlQ%
    ExitApp
if (ErrorLevel = "Timeout") 
{
 Run, Beep.mp3, Hide
 Input, Cont, L1
 if (ErrorLevel = "Max")
{
     WinClose, Beep.mp3 - SMPlayer
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> other programs (such as Microsoft Word) do not respond to keystrokes

That's because your inputs block them. Add the `V` option (which stands for visible), like

```
Input, KeyPress, L1 M T3 V
```

This is similar to `~` for Hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

```
loop {
   if(A_TimeIdle >= 3000) {
       sleep 100
       IfWinNotExist, Beep.mp3 - SMPlayer
       {
          Run, Beep.mp3, Hide
       }
   } else {
       IfWinExist, Beep.mp3 - SMPlayer
       {
          WinClose, Beep.mp3 - SMPlayer
       }
   }
}

^q::
   ExitApp
return
```

[A_TimeIdle](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TimeIdle) might be the right function in this case.